# EntityCollection - ICollection<InterfaceTEntity> - Runtime Issue/Quirk

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, entity-framework-6, t4

## Background Info

I'm using the Database-First approach.

I created a TextTemplate (.tt) file that generates interfaces from the EDMX file, also, I modified the original TextTemplate file included/produced by the EDMX file (project item) to have the generated classes implement those interfaces.

#### [Person] (Partial Public Class)

```
namespace TestSolution.Domain.Entities
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using TestSolution.Domain.Entities;

  public partial class Person : IPerson
  {
    public Person()
    {
        //this.CrewMembers = new HastSet<CrewMember>();
        this.CrewMembers = new HashSet<ICrewMember>();
    }

    public Person(IPerson iPerson)
        {
        this.PersonID = iPerson.PersonID;
        this.First = iPerson.First;
        this.Last = iPerson.Last;
        //this.CrewMembers = new HastSet<CrewMember>();
        this.CrewMembers = new HashSet<ICrewMember>();
    }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ICrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**As you can see in the code sample above**, I also added a constructor that takes the interface to initialize the Person class...

#### [IPerson] (Interface)

```
namespace TestSolution.Domain.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;       

    public interface IPerson
    {       
         int PersonID { get; set; }
         string First { get; set; }
         string Last { get; set; }

         //ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
         ICollection<ICrewMember> CrewMembers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `CrewMember` Class and `ICrewMember` Inteface contain:

- boolean properties (`IsCaptain` and `IsAssigned`)
- `Int PersonID` as a property, `Int CrewMemberID` as a property,
- and `Person Person` as Person of course. (I have tried `IPerson Person` as well).

---

## My Intention; The Issue

I intended to use `ICollection<ICrewMember>` for the Navigation. Then use DTO/Model/ModelView Objects/Classes that Implement those interfaces.

When I generated `ICollection<InterfaceTEntity>` types in the navigation property, I wasn't seeing any issues.. with EntityFramework.. until I attempted to update two Entities using the same context: `context.CrewMembers` and `context.People` in the same function.

```
public void UpdateCrewMemberModel(CrewMemberModel CrewMember)
    {
        var query = (from crewMember in UnitOfWork.DataContext.CrewMembers
                     where crewMember.CrewMemberID == CrewMember.CrewMemberID
                     select crewMember).First<CrewMember>();
        query.IsAssigned = CrewMember.IsAssigned;
        query.IsCaptain = CrewMember.IsCaptain;


        // Exception is thrown here 
        var queryPerson = (from person in UnitOfWork.DataContext.People
                           where person.PersonID == query.PersonID
                           select person).First<Person>();
        queryPerson.First = CrewMember.Person.First;
        queryPerson.Last = CrewMember.Person.Last;

        //Note that UnitOfWork uses a Factory Repository Pattern;
        //Commit just calls on UnitOfWork.DataContext.SaveAll() Method
        UnitOfWork.Commit();
    }
```

The issue I am having/seeing seemed to be with EntityFramework's Change-Tracking Feature. However, it is actually rooted with asynchronous operations within EntityFramework itself.

If I debug and step through the above method, **there is no exception**, and the database/tables updates properly..

If I run it without catching a debug point before the statement declaring queryPerson.. it will throw an exception ( a misleading exception regarding Person.CrewMembers having to be `ICollection<T>`)..

This certainly seems to be a timing issue

---

## Attempted Workaround/ Points of Interest

I attempted to remove the virtual attribute on the ICollection<> properties; didn't affect the issue.

I attempted to remove Lazy Loading; didn't affect the issue.

I attempted to commit the changes between the queries; did not affect the issue.

I attempted to perform to use `FirstAsync<>` on query; but I'm not sure if I'm even using it properly.. I'm still fiddling with this approach.

---

### *EDIT/UPDATE - (misleading) Exception, Stack Trace, and Target Site

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
{"The navigation property 'CrewMembers' on entity of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_1A1EF42B1FC8D2DD0084F803201DE1DE4CF6E704C5AE129D954BD5BEAB55826C' must implement ICollection<T> in order for Entity Framework to be able to track changes in collections."}

Source: EntityFramework

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.CheckIfNavigationPropertyContainsEntity(IEntityWrapper wrapper)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_ReferenceValue(IEntityWrapper value)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.SetEntityKey(EntityKey value, Boolean forceFixup)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal(EntityReference relatedEnd, EntityKey foreignKey, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean replaceExistingRef)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(Boolean replaceAddedRefs, EntitySetBase restrictTo)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(EntityEntry newEntry, Boolean replaceAddedRefs)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at TestSolution.Infrastructure.Service.CrewMemberService.UpdateCrewMemberModel(CrewMemberModel CrewMember) in c:\Users\brett.caswell\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestSolution\TestSolution.Infrastructure.Service\Services\CrewMemberServices.cs:line 67

TargetSite: {Boolean CheckIfNavigationPropertyContainsEntity(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper)}
```

---

### *EDIT/UPDATE - Question

*Though to ask this question may be improperly scoping the issue I'm having...*

When using Generic Type interfaces with the ICollection in Navigation Properties of the generated classes, How can/do I handle potentially unsafe threading instances(in my `UpdateCrewmMemberModel` method) that occur within/from EntityFramework?

Comment: This is very verbose, and I can't seem to parse a question. What is your question?

Comment: Your right, it seems more like a possible bug review than a question.. but my question really goes along with my intention; How can I use Generic Type interfaces with the ICollection<T> in Navigation Properties while handling potentially unsafe threading instances that occur within EntityFramework.

Comment: "a misleading exception regarding Person.CrewMembers having to be `ICollection<T>`" -- Can you please include the exact exception you're getting, along with the stack trace? Even if it doesn't point you towards the problem, it may show others what's going on.

Comment: I added the exception and rephrased my question.. I would like to reiterate (at least in this comment) that this exception isn't thrown if I step through the method in debug.. It also is not thrown if I comment out the first query declaration and the query property assignment statements.

Comment: How is CrewMember defined?

Comment: Do you get the exception if you load the crew member without tracking? E.g., `UnitOfWork.DataContext.CrewMembers.AsNoTracking()`

Comment: @SteveRuble, I do not get the exception.. but it doesn't apply the update changes to the CrewMember Entity when doing the UnitOfWork.Commit() either..

Comment: Looking at the code that throws that exception, it is checking whether `CrewMembers` implements `IEnumerable` (not `ICollection<T>`). But `HashSet<T>` does implement `IEnumerable`, as do all collections EF uses itself. Is there any part of the code that might be setting `CrewMembers` to `null`? You can verify this by providing an explicit property setter which throws `ArgumentNullException` if `value == null`.

Comment: BTW, the stack trace shows a call to `Enumerable.ToList` from your code. Your code doesn't call it. Is the code in this question exactly what throws the exception? (It's possible for the stack trace to be misleading, especially in release mode with inlining, so it's very well possible that the code and the exception do match up.)

Comment: @BrettCaswell, yeah, it won't track changes with that method, but it narrows down the problem a little. EF is getting confused when it's circumventing the proxy to get the value of the CrewMembers property in order to check whether a relationship already exists between your `CrewMember` instance and the `Person` instance it's materializing. Have you tried running it with `DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false`?

Comment: @hvd, there is nothing setting it null.. and it goes back to the exception being misleading, because it validates and functions properly if I step through under debug.. That is, if I delayed my current thread by 500 millseconds.. I'm sure it would process through with no exception..

Comment: @SteveRuble, I haven't yet.. but I suspect that might be a very helpful suggesting.. I'll set it up.. 1 sec

Comment: @SteveRuble, hmm.. suprisingly.. the exception is still occurring with proxies configuration disabled...The exception is now stateing: `'TestSolution.Domain.Entities.Person' must implement ICollection<T>`

Comment: One more experiment, then I give up. You say "I intended to use ICollection<ICrewMember> for the Navigation", but in the class code you have `public virtual ICollection<CrewMember> CrewMembers` as the property signature in the `Person` type. If in your actual code this really is defined as `ICollection<ICrewMember>`, does it work if you set it to `HashSet<ICrewMember>` rather than `HashSet<CrewMember>` in the `Person` constructor?

Comment: @SteveRuble , well, when I change it to ICollection<ICrewMember> for my intentions, I'm forced to change it to HashSet<ICrewMember> instances before compiling. HashSet<CrewMember> doesn't implicitly convert to type ICollection<ICrewMember>..

Comment: Also, I should probably point out that the relationship between People and CrewMember should actually be 1-to-1.. but it isn't setup that way; it is setup as a 1-to-many, so there is a Person property on CrewMember. and a CrewMember Collection on Person.. As a workaround, I have attempted to set the Person property type on CrewMember to both IPerson and Person. neither have affected the issue I'm having, and both resolved the first Query (CrewMember) object declared and saved to the DbContext repository without exception in their scope.. but again, the double IQueryable issue persists.

Comment: @BrettCaswell, O, right, of course, I forgot the bigger picture and `HashSet` isn't covariant. Anyway, I'm pretty sure it's not a thread/speed issue, it's an issue with the way EF 6 is acquiring the value of the `CrewMembers` property, but I can't quite figure it out. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you get this error if you are trying to use an Interface as your Entity (which is not supported by EF).  Is CrewMember actually an Interface by any chance?

If it's not an interface, but it is a class that derives from an interface, it's possible EF may be getting confused at some point.  Are you doing any Fluent configuration perhaps?  Maybe you are trying to map to the base class or interface which would throw this error?

Your code is actually a bit confusing, since you're supposedly using a "unit of work", but you're accessing your dbcontext directly, so effectively bypassing the UoW, but then calling Commit() on the UoW...   I would suggest that you probably need to rethink your data design here, and probably get rid of the UoW entirely, since EF is a Unit of work already.

Comment: @BrettCaswell - That is the problem, you cannot have `ICollection<ICrewMember>`.  This isn't currently supported, and this is a well known problem.  You will have to use `ICollection<CrewMember>`

Comment: EDIT: CrewMember is a partial public class, it maps to the entity type/base properly.. My modifications on the generator have it implement ICrewMember.. the CrewMembers Navigation property under the Person object is an `ICollection<ICrewMember>`, this is the intention.. However, the issue I'm having isn't the cause of the exception  I'm recieving. EF can resolve `ICollection<ICrewMember>`.. the issue is that it can't resolve it fast enough in whatever thread it's producing its runtime assembly in that validates the property.

Comment: @it doesn't matter if you *think* it works.. it doesn't.  You can't use it this way, regardless of whether it seems to work sometimes.

Comment: This post (as well as the comments) is not an answer. You are not being constructive, infact quite the opposite. The EF source is readily available on codeplex and this project is exploratory in nature. So making blanket general statements on an open source framework not working the way I think is wrong on at least 3 levels. I take a personal issue with the latter: without providing any particular valuable insight you presume to evaluate how and what I think, and my knowledge and familiarity with the framework and the mechanics? that's just obnoxious jargon.

Comment: @BrettCaswell - EF is not "open source" in any traditional sense, since it's firmly controlled by Microsoft. You can view the source, and submit patches, but they ultimately control what happens still. In any event, if you want to participate in the open source process you should be doing so on the codeplex site. You asked about a problem that is a officially not supported, and does not work. The EF team says it does not work. Yet you insist it does, despite not being able to make it work. ICollection<Interface> *DOESN'T WORK* and *ISN'T SUPPORTED*.  Under any circumstances.  Period.

Comment: So whatever...  You can be offended, and pretend you know better than the EF team all you want... but good luck with that.

Comment: Clearly there was some false positives going on in my implementation, particularly with referenced assemblies.. thanks for providing some point of resolution on the matter.

Comment: @BrettCaswell - Well, i'm glad you've at least come to a conclusion on it, even if it isn't what you had wanted.  I'm sorry things degenerated a bit in our discussion.  Unfortunately, especially when it comes to EF, there's lots of stuff that kindof-sortof seems to work (like 1:1 relationships on non-shared primary keys) but due to some implementation issues in the framework ultimately fail somewhere deep in the bowels.  This is just one of those cases.